# Navigate to New Screen on press item React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I want when I press on each Pressable of list it need to navigate to new page. Example if I press Horaires d’ouverture I need to navigate to Horaires d’ouverture screen, if I press TarifsIt need to navigate to Tarifs screen , and so on in my list

I do not Know How can I Achieve this, I have tried with below code, I worked for me but if list increased it will be bad experience to manually add if condition and show screen.

```
 let screen = [];

if (nestedId === "nc1") {
  screen = <HorairesDouverture title={title} />;
}
```

I am basically rendering to CategoryDetailsScreen and showing screen using if condition

```
import { useContext, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Context } from "../../store/context/context";
import { NESTED_CATEGORY_DATA } from "../../data/CategoryList/category-nested-list";

import HorairesDouverture from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/HorairesDouverture";
import Tarifs from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/Tarifs";
import ActivitesNautiques from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/ActivitesNautiques";
import PlanduSite from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/PlanduSite";
import MuseedelaMine from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/MuseedelaMine";
import MicroFolies from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/MicroFolies";
import Mediatheque from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/Mediatheque";
import Randonnees from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/Randonnees";
import Camping from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/Camping";
import Airedecampingcar from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/Airedecampingcar";
import AutresHebergements from "../../view/TourismeLoisirs/AutresHebergements";
import DemandeCivil from "../../view/Formalites/DemandeCivil";
import Mariage from "../../view/Formalites/Mariage";
import CarteNationale from "../../view/Formalites/CarteNationale ";
import DemandeDeSecond from "../../view/Formalites/DemandeDeSecond";
import Inscription from "../../view/Formalites/Inscription ";
import RecensementCitoyen from "../../view/Formalites/RecensementCitoyen";
import DeclarationReconnaissance from "../../view/Formalites/DeclarationReconnaissance";
import DemandeLicences from "../../view/Formalites/DemandeLicences";
import Modalitedinscription from "../../view/Enfance/Modalitedinscription";
import NavetteCommunale from "../../view/Auquotidien/SeDeplacerCategory/NavetteCommunale";
import TransportsRegionaux from "../../view/Auquotidien/SeDeplacerCategory/TransportsRegionaux";
import AssistantesSociales from "../../view/ServiceAuxHabitants/AssistantesSociales";
import CCAS from "../../view/ServiceAuxHabitants/CCAS";
import Permanences from "../Permanences";
import DemandePermis from "../../view/Formalites/DemandePermis";

function CategoryDetailsScreen() {
  const contextCtx = useContext(Context);
  const nestedId = contextCtx.nestedId;
  const [title, setTitle] = useState([]);

  let screen = [];

  if (nestedId === "nc1") {
    screen = <HorairesDouverture title={title} />;
  }

  if (nestedId === "nc2") {
    screen = <Tarifs title={title} />;
  }

  if (nestedId === "nc3") {
    screen = <ActivitesNautiques title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc4") {
    screen = <PlanduSite title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc5") {
    screen = <MuseedelaMine title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc6") {
    screen = <MicroFolies title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc7") {
    screen = <Mediatheque title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc8") {
    screen = <Randonnees title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc9") {
    screen = <Camping title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc10") {
    screen = <Airedecampingcar title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc11") {
    screen = <AutresHebergements title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc12") {
    screen = <DemandeCivil title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc13") {
    screen = <Mariage title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc14") {
    screen = <CarteNationale title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc15") {
    screen = <DemandeDeSecond title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc16") {
    screen = <Inscription title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc17") {
    screen = <RecensementCitoyen title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc18") {
    screen = <DeclarationReconnaissance title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc19") {
    screen = <DemandeLicences title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc20") {
    screen = <DemandePermis title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc29") {
    screen = <Modalitedinscription title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc30") {
    screen = <NavetteCommunale title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc31") {
    screen = <TransportsRegionaux title={title} />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc32") {
    screen = <AssistantesSociales />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc33") {
    screen = <CCAS />;
  }
  if (nestedId === "nc34") {
    screen = <Permanences title={title} />;
  }

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const categoryTitle = NESTED_CATEGORY_DATA.find(
      (i) => i.id === nestedId
    ).title;
    setTitle(categoryTitle);
  });

  // useLayoutEffect(() => {
  //   const categoryTitle = CATEGORY_DATA.find(
  //     (category) => category.id === catId
  //   ).title;
  //   navigation.setOptions({
  //     title: categoryTitle,
  //   });
  // });

  return <>{screen}</>;
}

export default CategoryDetailsScreen;
```

I have stored my data like this:

```
import { Image } from "react-native";
import Icon from "../../app/Icon";

class NestedCategory {
  constructor(id, categoryId, nestedCatId, title, color, icon, image) {
    this.id = id;
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.nestedCatId = nestedCatId;
    this.title = title;
    this.color = color;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.image = image;
  }
}

export const NESTED_CATEGORY_DATA = [
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc1",
    "cat1",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Horaires d’ouverture",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/balls.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc2",
    "cat1",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Tarifs",
    "#FBD243",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc3",
    "cat1",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Activités nautiques",
    "#F65C58",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc4",
    "cat2",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Plan d’eau",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc5",
    "cat2",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Musée de la Mine",
    "#FBD243",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc6",
    "cat2",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Micro-Folies",
    "#F65C58",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc7",
    "cat2",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Médiathèque",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc8",
    "cat2",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Randonnées",
    "#FBD243",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc9",
    "cat3",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Camping",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc10",
    "cat3",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Aire de camping-car",
    "#FBD243",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc11",
    "cat3",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Autres hébergements",
    "#F65C58",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  //tourisme

  //formalities etat civil

  new NestedCategory(
    "nc12",
    "cat4",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Demande d'acte d'état civil",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/passport.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc13",
    "cat4",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Mariage et PACS",
    "#FBD243",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/rings.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc14",
    "cat4",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Demande de Carte Nationale d'Identité et de Passeport",
    "#F65C58",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/resume.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc15",
    "cat4",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Demande de 2nd livret de famille",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/passport.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc16",
    "cat4",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Inscription sur la liste électorale",
    "#FBD243",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/rings.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc17",
    "cat4",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Recensement citoyen",
    "#F65C58",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/resume.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc18",
    "cat4",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Déclaration ou reconnaissance d'un enfant",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/passport.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),

  /* formalities Subventions start*/

  new NestedCategory(
    "nc19",
    "cat6",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Demande d'aide aux licences",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/passport.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc20",
    "cat6",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Demande de bourse au permis",
    "#FBD243",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/rings.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),

  /* end */

  /*enfance start */

  new NestedCategory(
    "nc21",
    "cat7",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Ecole maternelle La Source",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/family-room.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc22",
    "cat7",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Ecole primaire La Roche",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/art.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc23",
    "cat7",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Collège Alexandre Varenne",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/art.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc24",
    "cat7",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Lycée Professionnel Desaix",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/art.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc25",
    "cat7",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Ecole maternelle, primaire et collège privé Jeanne-d’Arc",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/art.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc26",
    "cat7",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Multi-accueil Les Bout’Chous ",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/art.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc27",
    "cat7",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Centre de loisirs Les Canailles des Combrailles",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/art.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc28",
    "cat7",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Relais Petite Enfance",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/art.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc29",
    "cat8",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Modalités d’inscription",
    "#FBD243",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/art.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc30",
    "cat13",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Navette communale",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/first-aid-kit.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc31",
    "cat13",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Transports régionaux",
    "#FBD243",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/first-aid-kit.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc32",
    "cat15",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Assistantes sociales",
    "#294A7A",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/balls.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc33",
    "cat15",
    "nestedCatId",
    "CCAS (Centre Communal d’Action Sociale)",
    "#FBD243",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/balls.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
  new NestedCategory(
    "nc34",
    "cat18",
    "nestedCatId",
    "Permanences",
    "#294979",
    <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
    (
      <Image
        source={require("../../assets/images/balls.png")}
        resizeMode="contain"
      />
    )
  ),
];
```

This how my frontend look like

[image]

And I think this is not the proper way to navigate to screen. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Object,

Create a object which contain all data of your screen, like

```
let screenData = {
nc1:{
     id : 'nc1';
     categoryId : 'cat1',
     nestedCatId : 'nestedCatId',
     title : 'Horaires d’ouverture',
     color : '#294979',
     icon :  <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
     image : <Image
       source={require("../../assets/images/balls.png")}
       resizeMode="contain"
     />,
     screen : <HorairesDouverture title={'Horaires d’ouverture'} />
},
nc2:{
     id : 'nc2';
     categoryId : 'cat1',
     nestedCatId : 'nestedCatId',
     title : 'Tarifs',
     color : '#FBD243',
     icon :  <Icon name="ios-arrow-right" color="#fff" size={20} />,
     image : <Image
       source={require("../../assets/images/walk.png")}
       resizeMode="contain"
     />,
     screen : <Tarifs title={'Tarifs'} />
},
...
}
```

Now you can get easily data from this object,

```
...
 const nestedId = contextCtx.nestedId;
 let screen = [];
 
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    screen = screenData[nestedId]&&screenData[nestedId].screen;
    const categoryTitle = screenData[nestedId]&&screenData[nestedId].title;
    setTitle(categoryTitle);
  });

 ...

 return <>{screen}</>;
```